# Modification to WooCommerce for WordPress featured image link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the link code that is being used for external products for woo commerce.

This is the code that generates the product image:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Image
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.3
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $woocommerce;

?>
<div class="images">

    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

            $image              = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
        $image_title        = esc_attr( get_the_title( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) );
        $image_link         = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
        $attachment_count   = count( get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) ) );

        if ( $attachment_count != 1 ) {
            $gallery = '[product-gallery]';
        } else {
            $gallery = '';
        }

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );

    } else {

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="Placeholder" />', woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() ), $post->ID );

    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```

So I just want to change out the image link to the external link url so if someone clicks on the picture, they will go to the external link instead of a blow up of the image

The code to do so is within the add to cart code, but I don't know how to apply it to the image:

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" class="button"><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></a>

<?php else : ?>

<?php
    $link = array(
        'url'   => '',
        'label' => '',
        'class' => ''
    );

    $handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $product->product_type, $product );

    switch ( $handler ) {
        case "variable" :
            $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ) );
        break;
        case "grouped" :
            $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __( 'View options', 'woocommerce' ) );
        break;
        case "external" :
            $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
            $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
        break;
        default :
            if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
                $link['class']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_class', 'add_to_cart_button' );
            } else {
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }
        break;
    }

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s button product_type_%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $link['url'] ), esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_attr( $product->product_type ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) ), $product, $link );

?>
```

Sorry I'm such a nube, but I can't figure out how to get the link code the same as the 'add to cart' link code, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy product-image.php to your theme or template (this will overwrite the Woocommerce default) and then change the following:

```
 echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" title="%s"  rel="prettyPhoto' . $gallery . '">%s</a>', $image_link, $image_title, $image ), $post->ID );
```

Where it says

```
<a href="%s"
```

Replace `%s` with your link, or you can register a custom post field and have a different link for each of your products.

You can ignore the "add to cart" code if this is all you are trying to accomplish. I might have misunderstood - so let me know if it's still unclear.